# PHP SQL Variables

Tags: php, html, sql, web, foreign-keys

Trying to make an update to two tables at once using PHP but the tables have foreign keys linking them. Normally I would set an @variable with LAST_INSERT_ID() but this won't work within the PHP code.

```
$newclass = "INSERT INTO PT_Classes(`Title`, `Details`, `Location`, `Time`, `Date`) 
        VALUES ('$title', '$details', '$location','$ntime', '$ndate'); 
        SET @last_id_PT_Classes = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        INSERT INTO PT_Calendar(`Date`, `Class`, `Details`) 
        VALUES ('$ndate', @last_id_PT_Classes,'$title');
        ";
```

However, I keep getting a

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @last_id_PT_Classes = LAST_INSERT_ID(); INSERT INTO PT_Calendar(`Dat' at line 3"

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: You're trying to perform multiple queries in one line, so the `SET` syntax is not a query unto itslef.